# Trying to pass input value of activity to another activity (loadurl)

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, android-webview

i'm trying to print the value of input of Activity 1 (class **first**) in the view.loadurl() of Activity (class **MainActivity**).

Here is my code:

**Activity 1:**

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/urlYoutube"
    android:layout_marginTop="95dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:hint="@string/guia_txt"  />

<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/btn_download"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    style="@style/AppTheme"
    android:textSize="23sp"
    android:textStyle="normal"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
```

**first.java**:

```
 findViewById(R.id.button).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int str = R.id.urlYoutube;
            Intent launchResult = new Intent(first.this, MainActivity.class);
            launchResult.putExtra("dato", str);
            startActivity(launchResult);
        }
    });
```

**MainActivity.java**:

```
    WebView view = (WebView) this.findViewById(R.id.webkit);
    view.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    view.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(false);
    view.getSettings().setSupportZoom(false);
    view.setWebViewClient(new MyBrowser());

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    int str = extras.getInt("dato");
    String s = "http://myurl.com/get.php?id=" + Integer.toString(str);
    view.loadUrl(s);
```

This everytime print the same value.

What this print:
http://myurl.com/get.php?id=**2131492970**

Can help me?

Thanks in advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you want to get the string inside that urlYoutube, right? for the EditText:

create the view like mUrlYoutube (or wherever):

```
mUrlYoutube = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.urlYoutube);

String str = mUrlYoutube.getText().toString();
```

What you're doing right now is to get the Resource ID int value from R ones the compiler does all the work.

When you have a resource, you must call it this way:

```
String str = getResource().getString(R.string.urlYoutube);
```

if int:

```
int str = getResource().getInteger(R.integer.urlYoutube);
```

Comment: ;) tell me later if that helps you.

Comment: This work, thanks mariano. p/d: Thanks for Preguntados too ^^

Answer (score 1):

if you do:   `int str = R.id.urlYoutube`;
you are getting the id of the widget after android sdk is compiling the views...
instead cast the view to a Edit text and use the method `getText()`.